# Assigning parent to an existing Row in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, parent

I am currently learning laravel 5. I tried to create a new user and assign it as the parent of an existing row named 'articles'. However I am getting the following Error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`test1`.`articles`, CONSTRAINT `articles_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert
>   into `articles` (`title`, `body`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values
>   (bhth, hvvtvt, 2015-05-21 12:43:01, 2015-05-21 12:43:01))

Can someone help me figure out what the issue is?

Comment: show your controller

Comment: can you show your tables schema too ?